# Importing Data into MySQL Database with SOURCE command

Tags: mysql

I have an existing MySQL database that I want to refresh with data from MSAccess database. I already have the SQL files created from the Access database with all of the insert statements. There are 3 SQL files, the largest of which is 8 MB.

The database is on an AWS server. In the past I've imported data using Sequel Pro from my Mac. This is very slow and subject to session failure.

Now I've figured out how to create the SQL files on my Windows VM and FTP them directly to the AWS server. My intent is to have a stored procedure truncate all tables and SOURCE the SQL files:

```
SOURCE /home/me/file1.sql ;
SOURCE /home/me/file2.sql ;
etc...
```

The stored procedure would also do any prep work on the tables and any post-import things needed like fixing foreign keys, etc.

The first problem is that this command doesn't work and causes syntax error:

```
set autocommit=0 ; source /home/me/CBD.sql ; commit ;
```

"source" is squiggly underlined and it says "missing colon". This happens whether or not I use the auto commit stuff.

Any ideas how I could do this?

Thanks...

Comment: Source is not a SQL statement, it's part of the MySQL interactive command line interface. It can't be put into stored procedures.

Comment: Do it from a shell script: `mysql </home/me/file1.sql`

Comment: Oh.... That explains a bit.  I guess what this means is I will need a command file on my Mac that does all of the things I was going to do in the SP: Truncating the tables, turning off foreign key checking, etc., and once the data is in the tables, THEN I can run a SP to do the complex stuff such as re-aligning the foreign keys with their parent keys, etc.  Thanks...

Comment: Maybe I should clarify. I have 3 Access databases to import. Each has auto-number index fields from 1...x. I'm importing all of them to a single database, so I need to let the AI columns properly, well, auto-increment. Then I need to update the child FK columns to point to the proper parent records again, then finally turn on foreign key checking.